# Thunderbird and multiple recipients

Tags: thunderbird, bulk

I want to send a bulk message to about 300 people in a club.  My ISP only allows less than 100 at a time.  How can I configure Thunderbird to send a message to each recipient in smaller groups, or better yet to send one out and then grab the next address and send it out, then on to the next one, etc??